# Как в input c JS задать, чтобы принимались только + числа и -

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно прописать в `input box`, чтобы он принимал целые значения **(макс. 4 цифры, + или -)
Не более четырех символов, если число +, или 5 символов, если число -.

Знак минус только первый.

Вот наброски моего кода:

```js
function f(iv) {

  iv= (iv) ? iv: window.event;
  var newC = (iv.which) ? iv.which : iv.keyCode;

  if ((newC >= 48 && newC <= 57) || newC == 45) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<input id="f" type="text" maxlength="4" onkeypress="return f(event);">
```

У меня он принимает знак `-` и в середине, и принимает `-999` только, считает `-` знаком.

Помогите поправить код.

Comment: Пример - https://jsfiddle.net/quh2scv6/

Comment: @soledar10 Между прочим, лучший вариант)

Comment: @soledar10 Между прочим, лучший вариант)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function f(elem) {
  var oldValue = elem.dataset.value || "";
  var value = elem.value;
  var n = Number(value);
  if (value == '-' || (!isNaN(n) && n <= 9999 && n >= -9999 && n % 1 == 0)) {
    elem.dataset.value = n;
    elem.value = n
    return true;
  } else {
    elem.value = oldValue;
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="f" type="text" onkeyup="return f(this);">
```

Comment: выяснилась проблема с вводом 0. Если ввести 00000,код допускает сколько угодно нулей.

Comment: и принимает 0,0 значение

Answer (score 3):

Другой вариант:

```js
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
  let v = this.value;
  let future_val = v.slice(0, this.selectionStart) + e.key + v.slice(this.selectionEnd);
  
  if (!/^-?\d{0,4}$/.test(future_val)) e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<input>
```

Если ничего не выделено, `.selectionStart` и `.selectionEnd` - одно и то же число: позиция каретки. Соответственно, разделив строку на "до каретки" и "после", добавив между ними значение нажатой кнопки, можно проверить будущее значение инпута.

---

(Называется «Регулярные выражения»)

`^` — начало строки, `-?` необязательный минус, `\d{0,4}` от 0 до 4 цифр, `$` - конец строки.

Если тест не будет пройден (вернет false), `!false` станет `true` и символ не напечатается.

P.s. Вариант Игоря надежнее, потому что обрабатывает неверный ввод через copy-paste.